# Is ARP Connection oriented or connectionless?

Tags: networking, tcp, connection, udp

Is ARP Connection oriented or connectionless? It uses TCP, but does that consider it connection oriented?

Answer (score 12):

> ARP Connection oriented or connectionless?

Connectionless - it's just a request and a response (or a broadcast just letting everyone know about something).

> It uses TCP

It doesn't use TCP - TCP is a layer 4 protocol, whereas ARP is glue between layers 2 and 3.

Comment: In the same sense would the following be connectionless too: HTTP, SMTP, SNMP, POP3, Frame Relay?

Comment: @Rick Not at all, you're comparing apples and squirrels - HTTP, SMTP and POP3 run on top of TCP, SNMP runs on top of UDP, and frame relay is for encapsulation of layer 2 traffic.